# How to send 'image' via POSTMAN? (Django Image Field)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, postman

I'd like to send image via postman like this and save to 'media' directory but don't know how to do this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB2A1.png)

And these are my codes that I use.

1. models.py

   ```
   class Article(models.Model):

        emotion = models.TextField()
        location = models.TextField()
        menu = models.TextField()
        weather = models.TextField()
        song = models.TextField()
        point = models.IntegerField()
        content = models.TextField()

        image = models.ImageField(default = 'media/coffee_default.jpg', upload_to = "%Y/%m/%d")
        user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        created = models.DateTimeField(default = now)
        liked = models.BooleanField(default = False)
        num_liked = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
   ```
2. views.py

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([])
def post_articles(request):
user = request.user
body = json.loads(request.body)

```
article = Article(
    emotion = body['emotion'],
    location = body['location'],
    menu = body['menu'],
    weather = body['weather'],
    image = body['image'],
    song = body['song'],
    point = body['point'],
    content = body['content'],
    user = user)
article.save()

serializers = ArticleSerializer(article)

return JsonResponse({ "success": True, "data": serializers.data })
```

3. serializers.py

   class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
   model = Article
   fields = ['emotion', 'location', 'menu', 'weather', 'song', 'point', 'content',
   'image', 'user', 'created', 'liked', 'num_liked']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, you don't need to do anything particular about file fields, you just tell it to make use of the file field:

```py
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets

class Article(django.db.models.Model):
    image = django.db.models.ImageField()
# rest of fields are excluded --TODO

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Article
        fields = ('id', 
                 'image', # <-- HERE
                 'menu', 'weather', 'song', 'point', 'content', 'location', 'emotion')   

class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'photos', PhotoViewSet)

api_urlpatterns = ([
    url('', include(router.urls)),
], 'api')
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^api/', include(api_urlpatterns)),
]
```

and you're ready to upload files:

curl -sS http://example.com/api/photos/ -F 'image=@/path/to/file'
Add -F field=value for each extra field your model has. And don't forget to add authentication.

or with [dothttp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShivaPrasanth.dothttp-code)

```
POST http://example.com/api/articles/ 
multipart(
    'image'< '<file to the path>',
    'emotion' < "emotion",
    'location' < "location",
    'menu' < "menu",
    'weather' < "weather",
    'image' < "image",
    'song' < "song",
    'point' < "point",
    'content' < "content"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, do I have to update 'models.py' and 'serializers.py' then??

Comment: Yes, you will need to update model and serializer both.

Comment: Also, make sure you are using multipart (dothttp/postman/curl)